# How to apply a Pandas filter on a data frame based on entries in a column from a different data frame (no join)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

As an example, I have one data frame (df_1) with one column which contains some text data. The second data frame (df_2) contains some numbers. How do I check if the text contains the numbers from the second data frame?

**df_1**

```
                       Note
0  The code to this is 1003
1  The code to this is 1004
```

**df_2**

```
   Code_Number
0         1006
1         1003
```

So I want to check if the entries in [Note] from df_1 contains the entries from [Code_Number] from df_2

I have tried using the following code: `df_1[df_1['Note'].str.contains(df_2['Code_Number'])]` and I know I cannot use a join as I do not have a key to join on.

The final result which I am looking for after the filtering has been applied is:

```
   Note              
0  The code to this is 1003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and see if it covers your use case: get a cross cartesian of both columns, using [itertools' product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and filter based on the condition:

```
from itertools import product
m = [ left for left, right
      in product(df.Note,df1.Code_Number) 
      if str(right) in left]

pd.DataFrame(m,columns=['Note'])

               Note
0   The code to this is 1003
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
df_1.loc[df_1['Note'].apply(lambda x: any(str(number) in x for number in df_2['Code_Number']))]
```

Comment: So I have got :

`df_i = df_1.loc[df_1['Note'].apply(lambda x: any(str(number) in x for number in df_2['Code_Number']))`



`return df_i`



But when I run this, it says ' Invalid Syntax'

Comment: Sorry there was had a typo, @sammywemmy fixed it. Should run now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly, you have to create 1 column in your df1 where the notes are with a list of numbers that are present in the Notes and then Compare the List column of numbers with the List column of the df2 where the numbers are present(both should be in list format)



#Extract Numbers from Notes
a_string = "0abcadda1 11 def 23 10007"

numbers = [int(word) for word in a_string.split() if word.isdigit()]

print(numbers)


list_test = "103,23"

#Finding common element from both lists the list
L1 = [2,3,4]
L2 = [1,2]
[i for i in L1 if i in L2]


S1 = set(L1)
S2 = set(L2)
print(S1.intersection(S2))

#If you want to find out the common element

def common_data(list1, list2):
    result = False

    # traverse in the 1st list 
    for x in list1:

        # traverse in the 2nd list 
        for y in list2:

            # if one common 
            if x == y:
                result = True
                return result

    return result


# driver code 

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(common_data(a, b))

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9]
print(common_data(a, b))
```